# How to change the color of slide menu in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to change the background color of this menu to the color of the title bar color. (Orange color) ("bar-assertive")

[image: Ionic Slide menu]

Here ionic code in app.html

```
<ion-nav-view name="content" ></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content class ="bar-assertive">

<ion-side-menu side="right">
<header class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
 </header>
    <ion-content class="menu-right-container has-header ">
        <ion-list class = "list-assertive">
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.feed">
                events
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.announcements">
                announcements
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.groups">
                Manage Group
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.notifications">
               Manage Notification
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.about">
                about
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer. 
in style.css changed the default values

```
.menu-right ion-content,.menu-right .item-complex .item-content{
color:#000000;
background-color: #EF473A;
}
```